# Unit tests slow execution on build server

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, xunit

I have a .NET solution that contains some Service Fabric library projects (.NET Standard 2.0) that are published as nuget packages. The unit-test projects in the solution (.NET Core 2.0) are using xUnit.

I noticed the tests are taking too much time when running on the build server, **comparing to previous builds**.

I tried running the tests in my local machine using Reshaper/Visual Studio or a powershell script and it takes less than 5 minutes:

```
$stopwatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

Get-ChildItem -recurse *tests.csproj | % { 
    dotnet test $_.FullName --no-build --no-restore;
}

$stopwatch.Stop()
Write-Host $stopwatch.Elapsed
```

But in Azure Devops the unit-testing task took more than 27 minutes to finish!!!

This is the Build pipeline/unit test task:

[image: Build pipeline tasks]

Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: Is this comparing of PS on your local machine VS build task on the build machine / or was the PS on the build machine as well?

Comment: I ran the powershell script on my local machine. I'll try it on the build server as well, using a Powershell task

Comment: I think this is too broad. It could be anything from "build server has too much load", down to some tests doing IO related things, that are simply different on that machine. I would first start by trying to get statistics for each test, and start comparing them. If only some test cases are much slower, or if they are allow slowed down in the same way.

Comment: @GhostCat same problem happens with other build agents. All tests seem to be slower compared to running in my machine. I don't see difference in other tasks such as restoring nuget packages or building the solution

Comment: While I agree with @GhostCat - my 2 cents on this the build machines are generally lower spec'd machines than what your dev machine is. Just a random thought - have you tried using something other than XUnit? Why aren't you using the default VisualStudio testing tools and libraries? Setting up XUnit might be another overhead.

Comment: @MaviDomates it's actually not my choice, the development teams are free to use their favourite unit testing frameworks :-) The thing is that this particular build had no problems before, but suddenly we started to have this issue

Comment: @MaviDomates it's not just 1 or 2 minutes difference, I could live with that... But from less than 5 minutes to 27 it's not normal

Comment: I have edited slightly my question. Basically I was trying to say is that running the tests on the build is much, much slower as compared to previous builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution in [Regression: dotnet test hangs for 15 minutes after test run completed on mac and linux](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9397).

Adding the following parameter to the arguments of the `dotnet build` task did the trick:

> -nodereuse:false

[image: Build definition - dotnet build task]

BTW the build agents are Windows machines, not mac or linux as mentioned in the above issue.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Thanks for this answer, got to know about the flag `-nodeReuse`. So, I was running a "dotnet" command via the C# Process call, and even after it was done with the dotnet execution it waited for like 15 mins to exit. So, with `-nodeReuse:false` it just exits instantly after the execution. For more details, search for "nodeReuse" in :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022